# setTime() throwing NullPointer Exception

Tags: java, timestamp, nullpointerexception

```
Timestamp[] lastreply = new Timestamp[100];
replyr = lastreplyr[i].getTime();
System.out.println("Replyr: "+replyr);
lastreply[count].setTime(replyr);
System.out.println("lastreply: "+lastreply[count]);
```

Console:

```
Replyr: 1321116689000
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at website.web.InboxReader.getLastReply(InboxReader.java:937)
    at website.web.InboxReader.main(InboxReader.java:55)
```

Why is lastreply getting null? In the code, count begins from 0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
lastreply[count].setTime(replyr);
```

`lastreply[count]` is null, because Timestamp is an object.
When you instantiate an array of objects then all the values are `null`. You need to insert references to objects first before start using them.

Comment: If it were null, why is replyr not null?

Comment: @PetarIvanov - You've got a copy and paste error. `lastreplyr` is fine, it's the `lastreply` array that he's not assigning new `TimeStamp` objects to.  Fixing it :)

Comment: I am sorry if this is a lame question but I actually don't get it. By using setTime(), I am instantiating the object only right. It should set the lastreply[0] to value of replyr.

Comment: no, setTime() doesn't instantiate the object - you have to call it on an exisiting object, but you never created any objects that are in the array - so they are all null. I am talking about `lastreply[count] = new Timstamp();`

Comment: @HPV lastreply is an array, all slots of the array contain null until you assign objects to them.